# ¿Como hacer un arreglo de objetos dentro de otra clase ? c++

Tags: c++, poo, método

necesito hacer un arreglo de objetos de tamaño 10 dentro de una clase diferente,
la unica manera que conozco para hacerlo es la siguiente:

(B es otra clase)

```
     class A
{
private:
    B arreglo[10];
public:
    A();
    A(string, int, B arreglo[10]);
};
```

El problema es no tengo del todo claro como deberia de ser el constructor por referencia, ¿como debo pasar el arreglo al constructor?.

¿Podría alguien explicarme como?...

¿Hay alguna forma de manejarlo con punteros?...

Answer (score 3):

> El problema es no tengo del todo claro como debería de ser el constructor por referencia, ¿Cómo debo pasar el arreglo al constructor?.

El constructor por referencia tiene esta firma:

```
A(const A &referencia);
```

Así que tu función:

```
A(string, int, B arreglo[10]);
```

NO es un constructor por referencia. El arreglo lo pasas al constructor al pasarle una referencia a objeto `A`, dicha referencia contiene le arreglo con el que quieres trabajar. Así pues, tu constructor por referencia podría tener un aspecto parecido a este:

```
A::A(const A &referencia)
{
    std::copy(std::begin(referencia.arreglo), std::end(referencia.arreglo), std::begin(arreglo));
}
```

En el código anterior, copiamos el contenido del `arreglo` perteneciente a la `referencia` en la `referencia` perteneciente al objeto que está siendo construido.

Comment: ¿ No vas a comentar nada sobre usar `std::array< >` ? O_o

Comment: To pa ti. Cuantas más respuestas mejor.

Answer (score -1):

Para acceder a una matriz de una clase que la usa como atributo lo mejor que se puede hacer es aplicar clases amigas, haci la clase B tendra acceso a los atributos privados de tu clase A, si no quieres complicarte mucho y el programa que estas haciendo y no es muy grande, puedes definir la matriz como global.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/).